# Delete duplicate lines in a file after a match in a particular subset of columns

Tags: bash, duplicates, matching

I've an unsorted file, containing row data disposed in many columns, as in this example:

```
10:23:55.521803 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 235 870 1 26601 349 910
10:24:11.771454 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 41 870 0 26601 349 910
10:25:18.858675 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 235 870 3 26601 349 910
10:25:18.814763 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 60 1247 0 38490 163 715
10:25:19.844738 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 60 1248 0 38490 163 715
10:24:11.771454 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 41 870 0 26641 389 920
```

I want to identify all the lines that, considering only the columns 4,5 and 6, are the same, and delete all this lines from the file.

Therefore, the result should be, in this example:

```
10:25:18.814763 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 60 1247 0 38490 163 715
10:25:19.844738 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 60 1248 0 38490 163 715
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't get your example. Why is the last line deleted then? And why do the remaining lines have the same values in col 4, 5 and 6?

Comment: If we consider the columns 4,5 and 6, line 2 and the last line have the same values, that are 41, 41 and 870. 

The remaining lines need to have distinct values in column 4,5 and 6, not the same with respect to any other lines

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**plan**

> - read the file and construct an key mapping to count occurrences of key fields
> - reread file only printing the records with occurences equal to one

**filter.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function get_key(k1, k2, k3, k4)     \
{                                    \
  if(k1 == "[")                      \
  {                                  \
    key = k1","k2","k3","k4"";       \
  }                                  \
  else                               \
  {                                  \
    key = k1","k2","k3"";            \
  }                                  \
  return key;                        \
}                                    \
                                     \
BEGIN                                \
{                                    \
}                                    \
(FNR==NR)                            \
{                                    \
  key = get_key($4, $5, $6, $7);     \
  a[key] = a[key] + 1;               \
}                                    \
(FNR!=NR)                            \
{                                    \
  key = get_key($4, $5, $6, $7);     \
  if(a[key] == 1)                    \
  {                                  \
    printf $0"\n";                   \
  }                                  \
}                                    \
```

**output**

```
$ ./filter.awk input.txt input.txt 
10:25:18.814763 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 60 1247 0 38490 163 715
10:25:19.844738 [INFO] eceb [ 41] 60 1248 0 38490 163 715
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I understand what is the plan, but when I run ./filter.awk input.txt output.txt in my terminal, nothing happens (the output file is empty)

Comment: need to run `./filter.awk input.txt input.txt` to see the output on stdout. or you can redirect to output.txt with `./filter.awk input.txt input.txt 1>output.txt`

Comment: the output file is still blank, and also on the screen nothing happens when I run the script.

I've copied your code in a blank file and made it executable.. any other thing to do?

Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry amdixon, the problem has been solved. It was due to the fact that I was experimenting with the wrong file. 

Thank you so much!